# Vb.net current user logged in POS

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I made a p.o.s software but when the user logs in the product table windows i need to display the name of the user that is currently log'ed in . The database is in MySql . I tried different methods to do it

```
 konecija.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from baza.korisnici where korisnik='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and lozinka='" & TextBox2.Text & "' "
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konecija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim kolicina As Integer

        kolicina = 0
        While READER.Read
            kolicina = kolicina + 1
        End While

        If kolicina = 1 Then


            ProductTable.Show()


            Me.Hide()

        ElseIf kolicina > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име веќе е во употреба !")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име или лозинка не се валидни !")
        End If
```

Comment: Can you share what you try

Comment: I tried to do a query but i failed to display the member

Comment: Then share your query and related information (e.g. database scheme, rows in the database).

Comment: From your (lack of) description it can be literally a million things that are wrong...

Comment: I have multiple databases USERDATABASE and PRODUCTSDATABASE, in products when you log in i want to show the user name that is loged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from the information that you have given us without seeing your code, I'm guessing that you have one form for a login and another that opens when the login is correct, with that being said

Try this

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "admin" And TextBox2.Text = "password" Then
        Form2.Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("please try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't know if you are having it log in via the database credentials as you haven't said otherwise, however try this and let us know how you get on.

If you don't want the user's name to show in a label, change it to where you want the name to show.

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM THANKS I JUST PASSED THE VALUE FROM THE LOGIN FORM TO A LABEL ON THE PRODUCT TABLE !

Comment: no problem at all, happy to help, if you found this answer useful, please make it as correct for the next person with the same problem. :)